# Is there way to add Colored text to discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I want my discord bot to send colored messages.

This is my attempt:

````
x = str("""```css\nh```""") 
await message.channel.send(x)
````

Any idees on how to add colored text to discord bot? Should i add it in the developer discord?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can add colored text, but if you want color, you can try using a [`discord.py` Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed). With that, you can try this:

````py
text = str("""```css\nh```""")
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Colored Embed",
    description=text
    color=0x0000ff
)
await message.channel.send(x)
````

Comment: @JACKDANIELS777 Care to explain *what* doesn't work? Remember that this is assuming that all the proper bot instances are set up.